# Pandas Return values based on a range of data with condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am working using python and pandas with the dataset below

| Name | Subject | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | Science | A |
| **Bob** | **Maths** | **B** |
| **Bob** | **Maths** | **C** |
| Cynthia | Science | C |
| **Dylan** | **Geography** | **A** |
| **Dylan** | **Geography** | **A** |

I would like to find names and subjects that have been repeated twice and display them exactly like the table below. The grades will only get concatenated by a comma if required.

| Name | Subject | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Maths | B,C |
| Dylan | Geography | A |

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find your duplicated rows based on Name and Subject columns using `duplicated`, and then use `groupby` with a custom `join`.

`set` is used to ensure a single Grade is returned when Grades are the same.

```
key_cols = ['Name','Subject']
df[df.duplicated(key_cols, keep=False)].groupby(key_cols,as_index=False).agg({'Grade':lambda x: ','.join(set(x))})
```

prints:

```
    Name    Subject Grade
0    Bob      Maths   C,B
1  Dylan  Geography     A
```

Comment: `','.join(sorted(set(x)))` If the order of the grades matters~

Comment: Yes. But I wasn't sure whether OP wants to first row to be displayed first, and not an actual alphabetical sort. Thanks for your comment though

Comment: Or possibly better: `df.drop_duplicates()[df.duplicated(subset=key_cols, keep=False)].groupby(key_cols, as_index=False).agg(','.join)`

Comment: Yes, this is a more concise one!

Comment: Or simply use `lambda x: ",".join(x.unique())` to retain ordering.